# svn pre-commit check commit message for ticket number

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I am searching for a solution how to edit the svn pre-commit hook for checking the commit message for a certain package.

Normally, the commit message only contains the ticket number #123456

Now I want to check, if the commit message starts with that ticket number is maybe followed by some comments e.g. #123456 ticket partly done.

Do you know, if there is something like a pattern in the pre-commit to check this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Pipe output of `snvlook log` to old good grep

Comment: You mean like this?

```REPOS="$1"
    TXN="$2"


     SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook  
     ICONV=/usr/bin/iconv  
     SVNLOOKOK=1  
    $SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | \
     grep "^#[123456789]\+.\=" > /dev/null || SVNLOOKOK=0  
     if [ $SVNLOOKOK = 0 ]; then  
      echo "Something wrong" >&2  
      exit 1  
     fi  

    set -e


    exit 0
```

Comment: Ok checked the regex, when I use 

...
$SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | \
 grep "[#][123456789]+" > /dev/null || SVNLOOKOK=0

...

with the message " #123 test description" , it does not work